# Convert View coordinates to Window Coordinates SFML

Tags: c++, view, window, sfml

I have an application written using SFML with a menu bar up at the top and a small box that lets you move things around under it. I need to convert the coordinates that I have from the View that I am using in the box to window coordinates so I can check if they are inside the box or not. I know that convertcoords converts window coordinates to view coordinates but is there a way to do that in reverse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the latest SFML version (i.e. directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML) or my [Nightly Builds](http://sfml.my-gate.net/nightly/)) you'll get the two functions [mapPixelToCoords](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp#L151), formerly known as convertCoords, and [mapCoordsToPixel](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp#L202), which is what you're looking for. Both functions are defined on the `sf::RenderTarget` and you can either let it use the view of the render target or provide an custom view.

Answer (score 0):

...um, what? I'm not sure what you mean by 'View coordinates.' I think what you need is CWnd::**MapWindowPoints**, in which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I probably should have mentioned in the body of the question as well as the title that I am using SFML

Answer (score 0):

mmm... I think there is no such function, you'll have to do it manually

http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=3257.0